# Multiple commas in csv file with delimiter = ','?

Tags: excel, csv, dataset, row, delimiter

I have a problem with a csv file that contains pairs "artist-genre",like the following:

```
artist,genre
Muse,rock
Nirvana,rock
Bon Jovi,rock
The Police,rock
```

The problem is that the csv delimiter is the comma (',') but in some cases there are more than one artist separated with commas, as in this line:

```
John Legend, Travis Scott, Teyana Taylor, Cyhi The Prynce & Malik Yusef,r&b
```

This situation of course creates some trouble when I import the dataset in the software I'm using to analyze them, so I'm looking for a way to edit the file and solve this issue.

For example is possible with MS Excel to select only the rows that contain more than one comma, then I can try to work on these rows singularly (they shouldn't be too much).

If you have a better idea I'd like to hear it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the data without parsing, so it is all in column **A**, then in **C1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))))+1,255)
```

and copy down and in **B1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)-LEN(C1)-1)
```

and copy down:

[image]

This technique finds the last occurrence of a **comma** in a string and uses that as a separator.